# Include field with array index in serialization of list

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using jackson, is there a way to add a field in serialized json with index of element in a list?

```
public class A {
  private static List<B> bs = new LinkedArrayList<>();
}

public class B {
  private String b;
}
```

Expected result:

```
{"bs": [{"index":1, "b":"b1"}, {"index":2, "b":"b2"}]}
```

Comment: Why do you need the index in Json? It is run time dependent when the list is created. Also depending on the serialzer and deserualizer you use, they can recover the list in original order without knowing the index field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own custom serializer like this:

```
public static class A {
    @JsonSerialize(using = BListSerializer.class)
    private List<B> bs;

    public A(List<B> bs) {
        this.bs = bs;
    }
}

public static class B {
    private String b;

    public B(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public static class BListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<B>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<B> listOfB, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfB.size(); i++) {
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("index", i+1);
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("b", listOfB.get(i).b);
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to write all properties of object in list instead of one by one? I try someone like jsonGenerator.writeObject(listOfB.get(i)) without success.